# Issue with git command due to missing forward slash

Tags: git

Cloning a repo gives the error below:

```
git clone https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git ~/.oh-my-zsh
Cloning into '/home/ubuntu/.oh-my-zsh'...
fatal: 'git@github.comrobbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The error is evident that there is a missing forward slash. But how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is this the exact output of the command? I really doubt it is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok found it -- the `~/.gitconfig` file contents were:

```
[url "git@github.com"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Updating to below resolved the issue.

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
        insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Comment: You should probably just throw away this piece of config and directly use SSH URLs in the first place ;)